# Self-extracting exe file fails to extract on Windows 10, but works after moving it via a Mac

Tags: windows, macos, zip

I downloaded self-extracting `W.exe` to a Windows 10 20H2 machine, but when I run `W.exe` to extract the archive, I get error: `failed to extract archive` (same result with security settings on/off).

- I downloaded `W.exe` from the same source to my Mac [call this file `M.exe`], moved it to the Windows machine, and when I run `M.exe`, it extracts successfully
- All kinds of exhaustive system tests show no problems, so I used WinZip to analyze `W.exe` versus `M.exe` and when I compare the detailed analysis, I see several differences between the files:

  - Location of end of central directory: 
     `W.exe`: `194,825,440` 
     `M.exe`: `195,002,183`
  - Relative offset of central directory: 
     `W.exe`: `194,825,309` 
     `M.exe`: `195,002,952`

Do these differences matter, and, if so, how is this happening?

Comment: `W` is corrupted. Download another copy directly to the Windows machine. Is it similarly corrupted? or valid?

Comment: Sounds like the first copy wasn’t complete.  You cannot extract incomplete or corrupt compressed archives.  There is no modern solution to fix corruption in a compressed file anymore so the only solution is to download it again or restore from a good know backup

Comment: File W was downloaded about 7 times with the same, repeatable error.  Also downloaded to a 2nd PC running Win 10 1909 and the same failure occurs.  Because file M from the Mac extracted successfully, I'm trying to narrow down possible causes.

Comment: Did two consecutive downloads to PC a couple minutes apart, analyzed both files with WinZip. Both  files have same size on HD but location of the end and offset of central directory is different.  All hardware checks out ok and drivers are all at latest versions.  Looks like something going on with Windows 10 or the PC's network interface.  Don't know yet if this is random corruption or if every download is being corrupted in a systematic way.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it matters, they should have same size, content and hash, the fact they don't, and the file M is fine, clearly states that W is corrupted, all is clear. As how did it happen, my first guess is during the downloading process. A lot can happen during the file transfer process. If network conditions changed for any reason, for example, disconnected for a while, the file will very likely be corrupted. If not during downloading, then the fault is on your machine. Most commonly filesystem is corrupted, fragmentation can cause filesystem corruption, so can sudden power failures. Try chkdsk in cmd to check your filesystem. If neither of the above is the case, then your hard drive has bad sectors, again this can have many causes, but hard drives are more prone to bad sectors the older they are.

---

### ***Update***

I seem to see a pattern here, if the machines are within the same network, and `chkdsk` & `mdsched` failed to find problems, if the file downloaded on Mac is fine but corrupted on Windows, then the issue seems to be Windows related; Try another Windows machine, this time with clean install, put it in the same network, and see if `W` is also corrupted; Try another Mac and see if `M` is also fine; If both are true, then the issue is somehow Operating System Specific...

Comment: I agree it matters since the central directory in file W is not where it should be.  File W was downloaded about 7 times to this Dell PC with the same failure.  The pre-boot diagnostics show no problems with the HD, RAM etc. On a 2nd PC running Windows 10 build 1909, the same failure to extract happens.  All 3 machines mentioned are on the same network, so same router.  Network drivers are all at the latest versions.  Any troubleshooting insight is appreciated.

Comment: At one point I switched the network on PC no. 1 from WiFi to Ethernet and got the same results.  I'm increasing memory on PC no. 2  and will try a re-install as you suggested.  Meanwhile, I downloaded file W to PC 1 twice within a few minutes and analyzed both structures with WinZip. The location of the end of central directory and also the offset in the two files differs by exactly 2 bytes.  I was checking if the internal structure of the exe file is the same on each download, but it's not.   Also, both files fail to extract - not surprised.

Comment: Repeated WinZip file compare test, this time with file M on the Mac.  Downloaded exe file twice within a couple minutes, moved to Window machine, then used WinZIp to compare internal structure of the two files (M1 and M2).  Result:  end of central directory and the offset are identical.  And they extract the archive successfully.  So we have the Windows machine changing the internal structure of the exe files and the Mac does not.  Same network but different OS and hardware.